# cygwin occures an error :"Segmentation fault (core dumped)", when running GIZA++

Tags: cygwin, giza++

I've ran GIZA++ on cygwin but it had an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". i cann't find any config file. Please help me, how can I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and could fix it by defining the environment variable USER. Either set in in your system properties, or in a cygwin bash shell execute:

```
export USER=Anything
```

GIZA++ appends the username to the output files.